# update google map route as user location change ionic 4

Tags: google-maps, ionic4, live-tracking

I am trying to build a live tracking with the route using Google Map JS version in ionic 4.
What I am trying to achieve is to give the route to the user from source to destination and update the route if the user chooses a new path other than the google provided one. The source is the user and destination is some point in the map.

I am able to draw route and update it if the user change the provided path using

```
startNavigation(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true })
      .then((position) => {
        this.userPosition = position;
        this.userVehicleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: this.map,
          position: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
          icon: this.vehicleIcon
        });
        this.addInfoWindow(this.userVehicleMarker, 'me')

        this.watchVehicle = this.geolocation.watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true })
          .subscribe(async (pos) => 
                {
                    // Calling the redraw function on every 25 meters distance travelled
                    this.drawRouteFromVehicleToDestination(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
            }
          }, (err: PositionError) => {
            // alert(err.message)
            console.log("error : " + err.message);
          });

      })
)



drawRouteFromVehicleToDestination(lat, lng) {
    let _self = this; 
    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    let directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#428BE8",
        strokeWeight: 2
      },
      suppressMarkers: true,
      preserveViewport: true
    });

    directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function () {
      let _data = directionsRenderer.getDirections();
      let _newData = _data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]
      console.log(_newData)
    });

    directionsService.route({
      origin: { lat: lat, lng: lng},
      destination: { lat: 27.673586, lng: 85.435131},
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      provideRouteAlternatives: false,
      avoidTolls: true,
    }, (res, status) => {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(res);
        directionsRenderer.setMap(this.map);

      } else {
        console.warn(status);
      }
    });
  }
```

But the issue is, it is sending a lot of requests to google API and which does not look like a practical approach to follow.

Is there any other approach I should follow using which I could track the route and update it as per user location change and also minimize the google ping?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you call `drawRouteFromVehicleToDestination()` very frequently (every time the vehicle position changes, from `this.geolocation.watchPosition`). One way to reduce the number of calls would be to "debounce" this calls, limiting them to every X ms at most, since probably it's acceptable to update every 200/300 ms. For example, you could use the lodash [_.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) function. For an in-depth explanation, see also the article [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

```js
this.watchVehicle = this.geolocation.watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true })
    .subscribe(async (pos) => {
        _.debounce(() => {
            this.drawRouteFromVehicleToDestination(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        }, 300, { leading: true });
    }, (err: PositionError) => {
        // alert(err.message)
        console.log("error : " + err.message);
    });
```

Comment: Seems like we can not use '_.debounce' in ionic 4 typescripts.

Also, I am using a distance limiter as call the redraw function after the vehicle has traveled 25meters  of distance. It also does do the same as the debounce.

But still getting a lot of pings to google map api

Comment: I missed the distance limiter, but that should already reduce quite a lot the number of calls, are you sure it's working? (a vehicle moving at 60mph moves by 25m in ~1s, so you should have ~1 call/s per vehicle on avg). For reference, for the `_.debounce()`, probably you would have to use `@types/lodash` in addition to the lodash library (but if you are already debouncing with other means, you won't benefit from this). If vehicles move along the same routes, you could implement a sort of cache for api results, but that will be hardly an option I guess.

Comment: yes, That is why I am looking for whether there is another option for this or not. The way I am doing corks perfectly but in the meantime is expensive

Comment: you can use the RxJS debounce operator. In this case you'd need to have
<code>
this.geolocation.watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true }).pipe(
 debounce(() => timer(300))
).subscribe(...)
</code>
You can check more on debounce here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html